# Python optimization with a solver

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, solver, minimize

I have a question about solvers. I've read a lot about them and also here on stackoverflow, but I have stil some questions about the mode of operation.

I wanna start with a simple `scipy.optimize.minimize`. Therefore I use the following code:

```
p_min = minimize(fun, p_start, method='BFGS', jac=None, hess=None, tol=None, options={ 'maxiter': 1000})
```

I use the `BFGS` method with 1000 iterations. p_start is my start value. My function is a full cash flow calculation, where I must find the minimum price, with the adjusted present value equal to zero. I need a solver for this case since I have a forcasted price and at all times compare my price with the forecast and use the higher one.

My question is, how can I define the function? Should my entire cash flow calculation be the function? And how can I define it that way? I am grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function have to be the entire flow calculation (unless there is some constant part, but this depend on the formula you use). The function have to be defined using a regular python function. It has to be a function of one argument only. If there is additional parameters, you could use the option `args=(param1, param2)` for example:

```
def cash_flow_calculation(p, param1, param2):
   # compute the cash_flow 
   return cash_flow

p_start = 0
param1, param2 = 4, 5
p_min = minimize(cash_flow_calculation, p_start, method='BFGS', options={ 'maxiter': 1000}, args=(param1, param2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @xdze2! So `p`can be undefined? And is it nescessary, that I write in the beginning of my CF calculation, that `p_start=p`?

Comment: `p` is not undefined. The `minimize` function will call the `cash_flow_calculation` function many times, certainly starting with `cash_flow_calculation(p_start)` and afterwards with `p` values determined automatically by the minimization algorithm. I am not sure now, what do you mean by 'solver'?

Comment: Okay, yeah it was my fault...I haven't seen the `args` command in your example. Can I use for arguments `param1` and `param2` time series data too?

Comment: yes, the additional arguments could be data too, as soon as they are not function of `p`